# iBeacon is receiving abnormal RSSI signal

Tags: ibeacon

I developed an ibeacon-based ios APP, but the RSSI signal it received jumps between 0 and a normal value during beacon ranging(there is kinda like a pattern showing a normal RSSI signal every 4-6 zero RSSI).

I am trying to let my iphone have a real time response based on the RSSI signal received, but I won't be able to do anything with this much unstable signal. I don't know this is because of hardware or battery problem or anything else. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When ranging for beacons on iOS, if no beacon packets have been received in the last second (but beacon packets have been received in the last five seconds), the beacon will be included in the list of CLBeacon objects in the callback, but it will be given an rssi value of 0.

You can confirm this is true by turning off a beacon.  You will notice you will continue to get it in ranging callbacks for about 5 seconds, but the rssi will always be zero.  After those five seconds, it is removed from the list.

If you are seeing it bounce back and forth between 0 and a normal value, **this indicates that beacon packets are only being received every few seconds.  The most likely cause is a beacon transmitter that rarely sends packets** (say every 3 to 5 seconds).  Some manufacturers sell beacons that do this to conserve battery life.

For best ranging performance, **turn up the advertising rate to 10 Hz** if your beacon manufacturer allows it, and also increase the transmitter power to maximum.  This will use much more battery but will alleviate the spots you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Yes, I did turn up the advertising rate to 10Hz with max power.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Yes, I did turn up the advertising rate to 10Hz with max power. Then I want to take a shot to see what happens after updating to the newest OS, then within around 10 meters, I can keep receiving signals without zero. but once I beyond 10 meters away, I am still receiving the zeros back and forth. Is it because signals not being stable even with 10 meters away?

Comment: This probably means the transmitter output is very weak, and you are losing most packets by the time you get to 10 meters away.  This is not typical of the way beacons work when they are set to the maximum power allowed by  international standards.  You can solve this by figuring out how to turn up the transmitter power on your beacon, or if it does not allow that, get a beacon from a different vendor.